# Seeing exception in Quartz scheduler causing jobs to not run

Tags: persistence, quartz-scheduler

We are using Quartz 2.2.1 and are seeing the following exception occurring at customers and in our own site. The quartz tables seem to be corrupted.
Has anyone seen this or know how to fix it?

update

```
2017-04-18 00:01:38,685 ERROR org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX MisfireHandler: Error handling misfires: Couldn't retrieve trigger: No record found for selection of Trigger with key: 'DEFAULT.Delete PS Audit logs' and statement: SELECT * FROM QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'MFTScheduler' AND TRIGGER_NAME = ? AND TRIGGER_GROUP = ?
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve trigger: No record found for selection of Trigger with key: 'DEFAULT.Delete PS Audit logs' and statement: SELECT * FROM QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'MFTScheduler' AND TRIGGER_NAME = ? AND TRIGGER_GROUP = ? [See nested exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No record found for selection of Trigger with key: 'DEFAULT.Delete PS Audit logs' and statement: SELECT * FROM QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'MFTScheduler' AND TRIGGER_NAME = ? AND TRIGGER_GROUP = ?]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1533)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.recoverMisfiredJobs(JobStoreSupport.java:979)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doRecoverMisfires(JobStoreSupport.java:3187)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:3935)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.run(JobStoreSupport.java:3956)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No record found for selection of Trigger with key: 'DEFAULT.Delete PS Audit logs' and statement: SELECT * FROM QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'MFTScheduler' AND TRIGGER_NAME = ? AND TRIGGER_GROUP = ?
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.SimplePropertiesTriggerPersistenceDelegateSupport.loadExtendedTriggerProperties(SimplePropertiesTriggerPersistenceDelegateSupport.java:157)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.selectTrigger(StdJDBCDelegate.java:1819)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1531)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: try setting `org.quartz.scheduler.misfirePolicy =  doNothing`

Comment: Error message is wrong.  The SQL query is going against the QRTZ_SIMPROP_TRIGGERS table.  The record is not there. Does anyone know why it would have been deleted?

Comment: there is an open issue for this on github, https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/issues/85. Please comment on it.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.

I fixed it by removing corrupted records in database.

Adapted to your case:

```
DELETE FROM QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'MFTScheduler' AND TRIGGER_NAME = 'Delete PS Audit logs' AND TRIGGER_GROUP = 'DEFAULT';

DELETE FROM QRTZ_TRIGGERS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'MFTScheduler' AND TRIGGER_NAME = 'Delete PS Audit logs' AND TRIGGER_GROUP = 'DEFAULT';
```

Comment: this might resolve the problem but how do we make sure this will not happen again? since these rows are retrieved everytime application starts we might end up service down issues